# What loss function and metric should I use for multi-label classification in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Model's final activation is softmax.(output means importance in my case.)
I want to pick top 3, then I used
categorical crossentropy for loss function / accuracy for metric.

for example:
prediction : [0.44, 0.03, 0.01, 0.02, 0.30, 0.20]
true:        [1,    0,    0,    0,    1,    1   ]

Is it right to use them?

Comment: Depends a lot on the data you are working on and how much accuracy you can handle. Some data give good accuracy above 80% while in some you have to take of the best available. If this is the best option you have then yes.

Comment: Yes this is right

Comment: Oh, I felt that I should change my final activation to sigmoid.

Answer (score 1):

## What loss function and metric to use for multi-label classification?

For a multi-label classification problem, use `sigmoid` (*not softmax*).

For a loss function use `tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy`

For example, lets say you have pictures as *X* and *Y* is 5 boolean values if the picture has one of the following items: a house, a person, a balloon, a bicycle, a dog.  If a picture can have a house and a dog, then this is indeed a multi-label classification and the appropriate output would be *sigmoid*.

For your accuracy, simply use 'accuracy' like so

```
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy,
    optimizer='sgd',  # any optimizer you like
    metrics=['accuracy'] # <-- like so
    )
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to solve with top 3, but that will probably not help with a loss function or accuracy.  If you are trying to show the top three predicted labels, you can do that post prediction with something like `argmax` from numpy.